# AWS billing shows SNS usage without any topics?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-billing

I was going through my AWS Billing Dashboard and noticed, that I am using some of my monthly free tier SNS requests. However, I don't uses SNS in any of my projects. I checked the SNS console and Topics, Subscriptions and Platform applications all show 0.

I am mostly using `eu-west-1` region, but billing shows usage of both `1,000,000 Requests for Amazon Simple Notification Service (EU)` and `(USE1)`. The only thing I have in `us-east-1` is a lambda that uses a "Alexa Home Skill" as a trigger (and doesn't use SNS afaik). The billing shows 4 used request this month, but the skill is used much more than that, so I don't think that's the culprit.

I have only a bunch of lambdas, triggered with CloudWatch events, Alexa skills or API Gateway. Any idea why would SNS show up?

Comment: You could inspect your `CloudTrial` to check what's calling SNS API.

Comment: @Marcin, good idea! Not quite sure how to use it correctly, but I have tried filtering for all SNS EventNames. I have found `ListSubscriptions` and `ListTopics` event made by my user name, using a web browser user agent. I'm guessing that's me opening the console in browser? Does that count against my quota?

Comment: "First 1 million Amazon SNS requests per month are free". So, those 4 requests should not have cost you anything. Did the AWS bill show an actual cost?

Comment: Did you set up a budget for the account? It might generate from there